# Modules for Login, Session, User Management, Logging

Tags: php, drupal, frameworks, joomla, node.js

I am starting a web service which requires user logging in with Gmail/Facebook/Own or signing up and then cookies being setup so that the user can keep communicating with the server via sessions.
Is there a readymade module available either in PhP/Node.js which can take care of these routine things which every website requires ? If this what would be called a middleware or framework what are the popular middleware/framework for such routine things

The framework should take care of all aspects like storing user details in Database, send forgot password emails, user session management, user activity analytics, etc ...

With these taken care of by readymade modules/framework/middleware I can concentrate on core functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/) and [express](http://expressjs.com/) (which is based on connect) are popular node.js modules which offers web framework functionality. Connect has more lower level APIs whereas express 
include view engine and higher level abstraction. [Both](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki) also [support](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#session-support) database (apart from memory) backed session storage.

Comment: I had looked at Connect and Express but they seem to low-level and I would need to implement all the things , I am looking for something readymade

Comment: These two are probably the most popular modules with web framework functionality used by node.js community and if you need additional stuff you should probably hook it up with other modules which specialize on certain area. Things like send forgot password emails, Gmail/Facebook signup or even user activity analytics are too specific and dependent on target application.

Answer (score 0):

Try [RPX](http://drupal.org/project/rpx).